# Python ExifTool combining subject and keyword tags

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, exiftool

I have a python script using `exiftool` to update the meta data within a given PDF. The documentation and download for the `exiftool` can be found here: [PyExifTool](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/)

Below is my current code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from exif_tool import ExifTool, fsencode

    source_file = 'D:\\my_file.pdf'
    author = 'some author'
    keywords = 'some keywords'
    subject = 'some subject'
    title = 'some title'   

    with ExifTool('exiftool.exe') as et:
        params = map(fsencode, ['-Title=%s' % title,
                                '-Author=%s' % author,
                                '-Creator=%s' % author,
                                '-Subject=%s' % subject,
                                '-Keywords=%s' % keywords,
                                '%s' % source_file])

        et.execute(*params)
        os.remove('%s_original' % source_file)

        for key, value in dict(et.get_metadata(source_file)).items():
              if key.startswith('PDF:') and ('Author' in key or 'Keywords' in key or 'Title' in key or 'Subject' in key):
                print key, value


>>> PDF:Keywords [u'some', u'keywords']
>>> PDF:Title some title
>>> PDF:Subject some subject
>>> PDF:Author some author
```

The above code works and updates the PDF meta data accordingly. However , when I go to view the PDF meta within Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader, the values for both Subject and Keywords are being displayed within the Keyword field.

[image]

Over all, this will not be a critical issue in most cases, but I can foresee receiving many complaints over this.

I may just be missing some small configuration or setting, but I have read through the documentation and I have not been able to find anything to get around this.

Does anybody have any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to fix this, and this is what I came up with. In order to prevent the Subject and Keywords from being combined within the Keyword field, there are a few more tags that need to be updated using `Exiftool`.

```
params = map(fsencode, ['-PDF:Subject=%s' % subject,
                        '-XMP:Subject=',
                        '-PDF:Title=%s' % title,
                        '-XMP:Title=',
                        '-PDF:Author=%s' % author,
                        '-XMP:Author=',
                        '-PDF:Keywords=%s' % keywords,
                        '-XMP:Keywords=',
                        '-overwrite_original',
                        '%s' % source_file])
```